# Issue with Start Date and End Date in SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I'm trying to delete the time-related information when I want to add a Calendar event. I did check the Event content type which has "Date only" option selected. However, the same is not reflecting in the Calendar. It still shows the time-related info.

I even tried creating a new content type based on the event view and still no luck.

If I add new date columns in the Calendar, and when trying to create an event with different Start Date and End Date, it shows up in a single cell in Calendar view.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you need to delete the time data? If it is about display, you may hide the the field with CSS. Or you may set every event a "all day" event.

Comment: Hi Mark, I agree that you can hide the time using CSS. But in the actual list, it still takes the time 12:00 AM for both Start and End date fields

Comment: What is the problem using 12:00 for both start and end, if you don't care the time after all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calculated field and set its value to this :

```
=CONCATENATE(YEAR([StartDate]))
```

Then you can display only this field and hide the defaults start and end dates.

Edit: This will only display the year part of the date, but I'm sure you'll find how you can display exactly what you want (month, day, ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create new `Start date` and `End date` with `date only` field, it will consider time as `12:00 AM`. So if you select 4/5/2016 to 5/5/2016, It will show in single cell only.